# Add new card is not being called in Stripe PaymentOptionViewController

Tags: swift, swiftui, stripe-payments

I am trying to implement Stripe Add Payment Method in SwiftUI. So a user can add a payment method or select from listed. After many days of searching I was able to implement a working PaymentOptionsView. However, when add new card is clicked it does not display the STPAddCardViewController to enter new payment methods

Here is the code that display the payment option

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import Stripe

struct PaymentOptionsView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
  func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
    Coordinator(self)
 }

class Coordinator: NSObject, STPPaymentOptionsViewControllerDelegate {
    var control: PaymentOptionsView

    init(_ control: PaymentOptionsView) {
        self.control = control
    }

    // Implement required delegate methods here:
    func paymentOptionsViewControllerDidCancel(_ paymentOptionsViewController: STPPaymentOptionsViewController) {

    }

    func paymentOptionsViewControllerDidFinish(_ paymentOptionsViewController: STPPaymentOptionsViewController) {

    }

    func paymentOptionsViewController(_ paymentOptionsViewController: STPPaymentOptionsViewController, didFailToLoadWithError error: Error) {

    }
}

func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<PaymentOptionsView>) -> STPPaymentOptionsViewController {
      let config = STPPaymentConfiguration()
      //          config.requiredBillingAddressFields = .none
      config.appleMerchantIdentifier = "dummy-merchant-id"

    return STPPaymentOptionsViewController(configuration: config, theme: STPTheme(), apiAdapter: STPCustomerContext(keyProvider: MyAPIClient()), delegate: context.coordinator)
  }


 func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: STPPaymentOptionsViewController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<PaymentOptionsView>) { }
 }
```

and here is APIClient

```
class MyAPIClient: NSObject, STPCustomerEphemeralKeyProvider {


func createCustomerKey(withAPIVersion apiVersion: String, completion: @escaping STPJSONResponseCompletionBlock) {

    let customerId = "cus_LoK4MNElrbzeVg"
     let url = "https://us-central1-test-mmmm.cloudfunctions.net/app/createEphemeralKey"
    
     
     AF.request(url, method: .post, parameters: [
         "api_version": "2020-08-27",
         "customerId": customerId,
         ])
         .validate(statusCode: 200..<300)
         .responseJSON { responseJSON in
             switch responseJSON.result {
             case .success(let json):
                 completion(json as? [String: AnyObject], nil)
             case .failure(let error):
                 print("Error creating customer Key (retrieving ephemeral key) with Alamofire. See: MyAPIClient - func createCustomerKey")
                 completion(nil, error)
             }
     }
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong and How do I implement the add new card method?

Comment: "Add new card is not being card in Stripe PaymentOptionViewController"  What does 'being card' mean in English?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code actually works fine. I was initially presenting PaymentOptionsView through .sheet(isPresented: so it does not allowing transition to a new view when the add card button is pressed. When the PaymentOptionsView is presented as

```
  .background( // add a hidden `NavigationLink` in the background
                          NavigationLink(destination:  PaymentOptionsView(), isActive: $showPaymentSheet) {EmptyView()}
                          .hidden()
                      )
```

everythings works. when the add new card button is pressed, the view transition to STPAddCardViewController perfectly.