# Swift - How can cardParams be obtained from STPPaymentOptionsViewController

Tags: swift, swiftui, stripe-payments

I want to complete the addition of new payment method that I implemented in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68384118/add-new-card-is-not-being-card-in-stripe-paymentoptionviewcontroller). This save and reuse [stripe tutorial](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-and-reuse) shows that cardParams and billingDetails need to be passed to STPPaymentMethodParams. How to I get the cardParams and billingDetails from STPPaymentOptionsViewController?

This is the code that produce the STPPaymentOptionsViewController and then display the STPAddCardViewController when add card button is pressed.

```js
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import Stripe

struct PaymentOptionsView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
  func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
    Coordinator(self)
 }

class Coordinator: NSObject, STPPaymentOptionsViewControllerDelegate {
    var control: PaymentOptionsView

    init(_ control: PaymentOptionsView) {
        self.control = control
    }

    // Implement required delegate methods here:
    func paymentOptionsViewControllerDidCancel(_ paymentOptionsViewController: STPPaymentOptionsViewController) {

    }

    func paymentOptionsViewControllerDidFinish(_ paymentOptionsViewController: STPPaymentOptionsViewController) {

    }

    func paymentOptionsViewController(_ paymentOptionsViewController: STPPaymentOptionsViewController, didFailToLoadWithError error: Error) {

    }
}

func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<PaymentOptionsView>) -> STPPaymentOptionsViewController {
      let config = STPPaymentConfiguration()
      //          config.requiredBillingAddressFields = .none
      config.appleMerchantIdentifier = "dummy-merchant-id"

    return STPPaymentOptionsViewController(configuration: config, theme: STPTheme(), apiAdapter: STPCustomerContext(keyProvider: MyAPIClient()), delegate: context.coordinator)
  }


 func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: STPPaymentOptionsViewController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<PaymentOptionsView>) { }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

STPPaymentOptionsViewController by design only returns you a PaymentMethod and not the raw card details.

Since the STPPaymentOptionsViewControllerDelegate returns you a `STPPaymentOption`, you can cast it to a `STPPaymentMethod` and then get the `billingDetails` for that PaymentMethod.

In your `didSelect()` delegate method,  you can cast it like:

```
if let paymentMethod = paymentOption as? STPPaymentMethod {
    print(paymentMethod.stripeId)
}
```

https://stripe.dev/stripe-ios/docs/Classes/STPPaymentMethod.html#/c:@M@Stripe@objc(cs)STPPaymentMethod(py)billingDetails

Comment: How can I cast it to a STPPaymentMethod from the  PaymentOptionsView in SO question?

Comment: added to my answer

Comment: do you mean paymentOptionsViewControllerDidFinish. I updated the question with the code

Comment: yes whichever method returns you a `paymentOption`, I believe `didSelect()` also returns you a `paymentOption`